# Custom sort order of list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have lists such as:

```
mylist1 = ['alpha', 'green']
mylist2 = ['blue', 'alpha', 'red']
```

I want to sort these two lists by this custom ordered list: `['red','blue','green','alpha']`

so that `mylist1 = ['green', 'alpha']`
and `mylist2 = ['red','blue','alpha']`

How can i do this in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Demonstration**:

```
>>> mylist1 = ['alpha', 'green']
>>> mylist2 = ['blue', 'alpha', 'red']
>>> sort_order = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'alpha']
>>> mylist1.sort(key=sort_order.index)
>>> mylist1
['green', 'alpha']
>>> mylist2.sort(key=sort_order.index)
>>> mylist2
['red', 'blue', 'alpha']
```

**Explanation**:

The `key` parameter in `list.sort` causes the list to determine the order by comparing `key(element)` instead of `element`. For example, to do case-insensitive sort, you can pass a `key` function which makes the string lowercase. The lowercase elements are compared, but the original elements are preserved:

```
>>> x = ["age", "Bonkers", "cheese"]
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
['Bonkers', 'age', 'cheese']
>>> str.lower("Bonkers")
'bonkers'    
>>> x.sort(key=str.lower)
>>> x
['age', 'Bonkers', 'cheese']
```

Using `sort_order.index` for the key uses the index that element has in the `sort_order` list to determine the order instead of the element itself. So `'red'` uses `0`, `'blue'` uses `1`, etc... the result is that the list to be sorted gets sorted according to where each element is in `sort_order`.

Comment: I want to ask another question related to this original post. Should I create a new question or add it as a comment???

Comment: @mensah Create a new question

Comment: It depends how different your followup is.  Start out by editing your question, if it seems too different someone will probably tell you so.

Comment: `sort_order = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'alpha'])}` for a performance improvement.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: true that, but that line is longer and less obvious, and then you need `.sort(key=lambda el: sort_order[el])`. or `sort_order.__getitem__`. either way it doesn't look as nice, so I'd go with this approach unless the speed ends up mattering

Comment: @Caudiu: `key=sort_order.get`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: oh nice. and then it also doesn't break if the value isn't there. interesting indeed. i've been using python 2.6, so i really have to switch to 2.7 to take advantage of the dict & set comprehensions.

Comment: @Claudiu it would break on 3.x as `None` is the default not-found value and is unorderable in Python 3.x - so you'd have to use `lambda L: sort_order.get(L, '')` if you wanted it to be orderable and sort in some way

Comment: @JonClements: ah yea I was just thinking that too. Not sure I like the change, but might just be what I'm used to.

Comment: Cool, is there any way I can sort a list of list using the same e.g. `[['alpha', 'a'], ['green','g']]`

Answer (score 5):

Use the index as the key.

```
key=lambda x: customlist.index(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
>>> a = ['red','blue','green','alpha']
>>> b = ['alpha', 'green']
>>> filter(set(b).__contains__, a)
['green', 'alpha']
```

Instead of sorting the list into an order, we only include elements from the already ordered list `a` that are present in the source list `b`.

You could write that as `[el for el in a if el in b]` and optionally have `b` as a set if desired.

Of course, If you really wanted to `sort` it, then you should probably build an index lookup rather than potentially iterate the list multiple times (by keep issuing `.index`):

```
order = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(a)}
b.sort(key=order.get)
```

Comment: Not very Pythonic.  Can you add an explanation of what's going on?

Comment: @Dirk not sure I get what you mean? It has the desired output... just didn't physically sort the list, as the output didn't require a sorting operation to be the specified output