# Custom order list python

Tags: python, list

Expanding on my first question here: [Custom sort order of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408247/custom-sort-order-of-list)

`mylist1 = ['moi.alpha', 'moi.red']

mylist2 = ['test.green', 'test.alpha','test.red']`

and I want to sort it by this order: `['red','green','blue','alpha']`

so that:
`mylist1 = ['moi.red','moi.alpha']

mylist2 = ['test.red','test.green','test.alpha']`

Note that "moi" and "test" is dynamic depending on a value assigned higher up in the code...

Comment: Use `sort` with custom lambda key using `str.split` or `str.rsplit`. Th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same exact code as from your last question, with a simple split function when looking for the index in sort_order:

```
mylist1 = ['test.alpha', 'test.green']
mylist2 = ['asdf.blue', 'asdf.alpha', 'asdf.red']
sort_order = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'alpha']
mylist2.sort(key=lambda x: sort_order.index(x.split(".")[1]))
mylist1.sort(key=lambda x: sort_order.index(x.split(".")[1]))
print mylist2
print mylist1
```

Outputs:

```
['asdf.red', 'asdf.blue', 'asdf.alpha']
['test.green', 'test.alpha']
```

All you really need is:

```
def sort_list(lst):
    sort_order = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'alpha']
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: sort_order.index(x.split(".")[1]))
    return lst
```

Comment: Ok, code works fine. But what if I want to allow an element in the list that is NOT in the sort? It throws an error. Example: `mylist1 = ['asdf.random', 'asdf.red']`  

that 'random' word should NOT be included in the sort...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to last time, just extract the part you want before doing the lookup:

```
your_order = ['red','green','blue','alpha']
order = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(your_order)}
mylist2.sort(key=lambda L: order.get(L.partition('.')[2]))
```

Comment: your_order = ['red','green','blue','alpha'] ???

Comment: @mensah yeah - I've added that in